# Examples of recent web sites/IOS stuff with great or innovative user interface sound design/sonification ?

Tags: design, sonification, interface, websites

Hi mates,

I am looking for web sites with  successful sound design (no matter the technology behind). I don't mean background music but interactive sounds only.
Thanks !

Xavier

Answer (score 1):

Two quite different examples jump to mind. The first is *[Devine Sound](http://www.devinesound.net/)*. Very simple, minimal bleeps on button clicks as well as some other nice interactive sounds throughout. Minimal, sleek and very effective.

The second is *[La Gaité Lyrique - Experience](http://www.gaite-lyrique.net/experience/)*. A very deep, immerse user experience with a whole host of interactive sounds. The first time I visited this site I spent ages exploring it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Colin. I cannot believe that you are the only one to have suggestions about it. Interactive sonification is a promising area. Mates, don't you have any other successfull interface sound design references to give to the community (websites, video games, handheld devices and so on...)?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Xavier,

I just remembered this [Amon Tobin experiment](http://www.amontobin.com/field/) that's kind of intriguing. I think the sound design could have been more immersive, but it's an interesting example. Generally though, this raises the question of whether it's actually a good thing to have lots of interface style sound on a website. For me, I only want sites to make sound if their purpose is to be an audio/audio-visual experience, otherwise I can't listen to music when browsing the web etc...

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since this question was active, but today I came across this acoustic ecology website which I think is awesome in terms of interactive sound design. Great BG ambiances, nice slick rollover sfx, left/right panning response to mouse movements. Plus the subject manner is very interesting too!

[Arte Sound Ecology](http://ecologiesonore.arte.tv/)